# PHP recursive array copy

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array of arrays (source below), where my keys and values are arbitrary strings.  I want to create a new array (desired below), where the hierarchy stays the same, but every KEY is restructured into its own array, with the key itself becoming a 'title' value, and any subarrays are continued under 'children'.

How can I accomplish this using a recursive function that takes &$source and &$destination arrays, and populates the destination array accordingly?

Source Array:

```
Array (
    [Alpha] => Array (
        [Red] => one
        [Blue] => two
    )
    [Bravo] => Array (
        [Blue] => three
    )
)
```

Desired Array:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [title] => Alpha
        [children] => Array (
                    [0] Array([title] => Red, [children]= > false)
                    [1] Array([title] => Blue, [children]= > false)
        )
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [title] => Bravo
                    [0] Array([title] => Blue, [children]= > false)
        )
    )
)
```

Note: I don't care about the final nodes/leafs in my new array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do te conversion without passing a reference to the destination array.

```
function convert_array($from){
    if(!is_array($from)){
        return false;
    }
    $to = array();
    foreach($from as $k=>$v){
        $to[] = array(
            'title' => $k,
            'children' => convert_array($v)
        );
    }
    return $to;
}
```

[Codepad example](http://codepad.org/cdY8F6E1)

Comment: Thanks, works great.  BTW what is the significance of using $to[] versus just $to in the foreach?  Only $to[] seems to work, but $to is still ok syntax-wise.

Comment: Using `$to[]` you are appending an element to the array (the same as using `array_push`), using `$to` you are overwriting the array each time.

Answer (score 1):

I have programmed array recursively.

```
$a = array(
    'Alpha' => array('Red' => 'one', 'Blue' => 'two'),
    'Bravo' => array('Blue' => 'three'));


function copyarray($datas){
    $arr = array();

            if(is_array($datas)){
                foreach($datas as $key => $val){
                    if(is_array($val)){
                    $arr[$key] = copyarray($val);
                    }else
                    $arr[$key]=$val;
                }
            }
            return $arr;
}

echo "<pre>";print_r(copyarray($a));
```